# Dropdown is not populated with KnockoutJS and Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I am trying to populate a dropdown list using knockoutjs from an ajax source that returns json. This select has to get updated when changing the value of another dropdown.

This is my model:

```
var self = this,
    getClientsRoute = "GetContactsFromCompany";

self.selectedCompany = ko.observable();
self.contacts = ko.computed(function getContactsFromCompany() {
    var companyId = self.selectedCompany();
    if (companyId != "" && companyId != undefined) {
        return $.ajax(getClientsRoute, {
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'companyId=' + companyId
        });
    } else {
        return [];
    }             
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="Client.Id" data-bind="options: contacts,optionsText: 'Name',optionsValue: 'Id'">
</select>
```

And this is my method that return the JSON string (I´m using .NET MVC):

```
public JsonResult GetContactsFromCompany(int companyId)
    {
        var contacts = _db.Contacts.Where(c => c.CompanyId == companyId).Select(c =>
            new
            {
                Id = c.Id.ToString(),
                Name = c.Name.ToString()
            }).ToList();

        return Json(contacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have seen other solutions to this but I think using the 'computed' method is more clean. Everything seems to work ok, I receive my json data but the dropdown is not populated. I have copied the json string returned by the server and created an observableArray with it and works perfectly, so why is it not working when getting the data from the server?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `$.ajax` is not the result of the ajax call.  You need to provide a `success` handler that will receive the data upon completion of the AJAX call (ajax calls are asynchronous).  What you'll want to do is have a separate observable for your `contacts` and then hook up a subscription to the `companyId` and do your ajax call whenever `companyId` changes:

```
self.companyId = ko.observable();
self.contacts = ko.observableArray([]);
self.companyId.subscribe(function() { self.loadContacts(); });

self.loadContacts = function() {
    $.ajax(getClientsRoute, {
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'companyId=' + self.companyId(),
        success: function(data) { self.contacts(data); }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick, that was exactly the problem. I would like to extend your answer adding that what $.ajax returns is a [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR). Another thing I have found is that success, error and complete events are going to be replaced by their equivalents methods on a [Deferr object](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) that follows a 'Promise' interface.